# Specifying a Custom Date Range in Googleads API TargetingIdeaService

Tags: python, api, google-ads-api

I am trying to use the Googleads API TargetingIdeaService to plan budget and get forecast for a list of keywords, as in Keyword Planner:

[Keyword Planner Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtFwb.png)

I want to specify the date range as next year (for example, 20180301~20190228), but I can't find any parameters or syntax that allow me to do so. The MonthlySearchVolumeAttribute is for selecting data for the past 12 months, so that doesn't seem to work for the situation.

Below is my python script for defining the selector:

```
selector = {
    'searchParameters': [
        {
            'xsi_type': 'RelatedToQuerySearchParameter',
            'queries': keyword_list
        },
        {
            # Location setting (optional)
            'xsi_type': 'LocationSearchParameter',
            'locations': [{'id': '2840'}] #US
        },
        {
            # Language setting (optional).
            'xsi_type': 'LanguageSearchParameter',
            'languages': [{'id': '1000'}] #English
        },
        {
            # Network search parameter (optional)
            'xsi_type': 'NetworkSearchParameter',
            'networkSetting': {
                'targetGoogleSearch': True,
                'targetSearchNetwork': False,
                'targetContentNetwork': False,
                'targetPartnerSearchNetwork': True
            }
        }

    ],
    'ideaType': 'KEYWORD',
    'requestType': 'STATS',
    'requestedAttributeTypes': ['KEYWORD_TEXT', 'SEARCH_VOLUME','COMPETITION','AVERAGE_CPC'],

    # Configure the selector's Paging to limit the number of results returned by a single request
    'paging': {
        'startIndex': str(offset),
        'numberResults': str(PAGE_SIZE)
    },
}
```

Is there anything I can do to achieve my goal? Thanks!